# "Short overhead" or "small overhead"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Regarding the header (overhead) part of a network packet (made of several bytes), should one say said packet has a small overhead or a short overhead if it uses very few bytes.

Comment: Why can't you say "short header"?

Comment: Small overhead.

Comment: The packet  has *low overhead.*

Answer (score 2):

The relevant definition of *[overhead](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overhead)* here is:-

> the general, fixed cost of running a business, as rent, lighting, and
>   heating expenses, which cannot be charged or attributed to a specific
>   product or part of the work operation. [Random House Dictionary]

Its appearance in the computing world is a metaphoric use of this; the *overhead* of the packet is a cost not attributable directly to any part of the packet. Since the cost incurred might be a number of different things (waiting time, telephone bill, user boredom) and not all of these could be said to be *short*, a *small overhead* would sound more natural.

Comment: In computing, an *overhead* would indicate additional resource requirements (say bandwidth, parameters) to transmit the packet over a network. Since it almost always boils down to size, I guess **small overhead** is the right option.